# conditional statement inside printf

Tags: c, linux, casting

What is wrong with the code. why cant the conditional statement is executing inside printf.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ch,hc;
    ch=getchar();
    printf("character entered by you is :- %c\n",ch);
    printf("letter in capital is %c\n",(((char(ch) >='a') && (char(ch)<='z'))?(ch-32):(ch)));
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to understand.

Comment: `char(ch)` should just be `ch` (x2).

Comment: This is not (inside your  `printf`) a conditional *statement* but a [conditional expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) using the [ternary `?:` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: BTW, to convert a letter to uppercase, better use [toupper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper). However, be aware of [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and see http://utf8everywhere.org/ ; then the conversion is not that simple, because you need to parse UTF-8 perhaps using [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/)

Comment: Read also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: This `char(ch)` does not seem to be C.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch UTF-8 is the least of your problems if you want to do case conversion "for real". For example, the uppercase version of `ß` is `SS` (not a single character) and the uppercase version of `i` is either `I` or `İ` (depending on the language you're in). In general, case conversions are locale dependent.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is not a function. You can't call `char(ch)`. If you want to do type casting, that's done like this:

```
(char) ch
```

Also, you don't have to cast an `int` to a `char` to do a comparison with a character. This is completely valid:

```
ch >= 'a'
```

even if `ch` is an `int`.

So, knowing this, you can change the `printf` line to:

```
printf("letter in capital is %c\n", ( ch >= 'a' ) && (ch <= 'z') ? (ch-32) : (ch));
```

Comment: Character literals in fact *are* `int`s.

Comment: And `'a'` is an `int` too.

Comment: Wat? Are they not `char`?

Comment: Yes typecasting is wrong here, it can not be done like char (ch), to do the typecasting use (char) ch.